# CommandConverter - Valid exception or .NET Bug

Tags: .net, exception, icommand

I'm getting an exception in my C#/.NET application that reads:

> 'CommandCoverter' is unable to convert 'MyNamespace.MyDerivedFromICommandSubclass' to 'System.String'.

What I'm doing is fairly straight forward, as described by the [MSDN ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand_members.aspx) documentation:

```
public class MyDerivedFromICommandSubclass : ICommand
{
  // Implement interface
  ...
}
```

I have a [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx) with a [Hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink_members.aspx) on it.  The Hyperlink is allowed to have a [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.command.aspx) Property, which I set to my derived ICommand so that when the link is clicked, my custom action gets performed.

That part works.

Here's where I get into trouble: if I select the hyperlink and right-click Copy (or press Control-C).

Instantly the .NET framework throws a System.NotSupportedException with the exception detail above.  The stack trace shows:

> at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertToException(Object value, Type destinationType)
>   at System.Windows.Input.CommandConverter.ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)

At this point I resorted to [Red Gate's free .NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and looked at the source code to `ConvertTo`:

```
public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
{
  if (destinationType == null) // We know it isn't, it's System.String
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("destinationType"); // We don't see this exception
  }
  if (destinationType == typeof(string)) // It is, so control passes in
  {
    if (value == null) // It isn't, so this condition is skipped
    {
      return string.Empty;  // Confirmed we don't get this return value
    }
    RoutedCommand command = value as RoutedCommand;
    if (((command != null) && (command.OwnerType != null) && IsKnownType(command.OwnerType))
    { // Is a user-defined ICommand a known type? Doubtful. This gets skipped.
      return command.Name;  // Confirmed we don't get this return value
    }
    // It has to fall through then if no return is done!
  }
  throw base.GetConvertToException(value, destinationType); // BOOM!
  // value is my custom ICommand and destinationType is System.String
}
```

So the question then becomes, as all of this happens inside of .NET, am I doing something wrong, and if so, what?  Or, is this a .NET bug, and if so, is there a work around?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fantastic description of ICommand resides in this [blog entry by SkySigal](http://skysigal.xact-solutions.com/Blog/tabid/427/EntryId/189/Silverlight-Notes-Synopsis-of-Commands-Architecture.aspx), though I needed [Google's Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:bJ5vf5Nb3lEJ:skysigal.xact-solutions.com/Blog/tabid/427/EntryId/189/Silverlight-Notes-Synopsis-of-Commands-Architecture.aspx) due to blog configuration issues at the time.  Unfortunately, the end of the article where this problem is addressed is a little ambiguous in its wording about whether the ICommand should be static or non-static.

Turns out, however, there was [an article on dotnet mania talking about how copying a hyperlink with a custom command will crash](http://eric.burke.name/dotnetmania/2007/07/08/23.05.00) an application.

Seems this bug has been in .NET since 2007, at least, and that the problem is the code explicitly checking for "known commands," just as the Reflector analysis above showed.

.NET wants to serialize the command along with its parent object, and that's where the problem comes in.  The article's solution involves creating a helper object, which is ignored by the serialization process, which does the same thing as the command.

```
<Hyperlink Command="{x:Static myns:MyCommands.CustomCommand1}" .../>
```

becomes

```
<Hyperlink myns:HyperlinkHelper.Command="{x:Static myns:MyCommands.CustomCommand1}" .../>
```

with some backing code inside the myns namespace's HyperlinkHelper class as a property named Command.  It's clever trickery, and ought to be shamefully unnecessary.

Hats off to [Eric Burke](http://eric.burke.name/) for figuring this one out.

Comment: To do this in C#, rather than XAML, one does this:

    hyperlink.SetValue( HyperlinkHelper.CommandProperty, CustomCommand1 );

Comment: Required reading.  http://blog.hackedbrain.com/articles/UnderstandingDependencyObjectAndDependencyProperty.aspx

Comment: And this.  Attached Properties -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively this feels wrong; copying the hyperlink should copy the text, regardless of what the command does. However, you can work around the problem by implementing your own TypeConverter for your command class ([How to Implement a Type Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx)). Have it delegate to CommandConverter, except for CanConvertTo: return false from that method to tell the framework that your command cannot be converted to a string (or delegate CanConvertTo to CommandConverter also, then return a representative string from ConvertTo.

Comment: Thanks, and double thanks for the link, I'll have to give that a shot.  Agreed that this feels wrong; if one does a Google search for the error message, you'll see it's happening all over the place to a lot of people -- none who seem to be getting a reasonable answer (this by far is the most informative response I've seen on the topic). I'm guessing that it's trying to put a representation of not just the text but the ICommand in the clipboard, should it be pasted to somewhere else that can deal with it. That said, I don't know why it's trying to convert it to text by default. Thanks again.

Comment: Ran into problems.  CommandConverter is sealed, and TypeConverter when overridden wasn't firing any methods.  I managed to get another solution working, I'll add that in a moment -- but thank you, your ideas led me to much closer.

Answer (score 1):

Also banged my head on this one for quite a while. I would have added this as a comment to Walt Stoneburner's answer but seem to need more points first to do that currently.

Anyway. As the link to the original solution seem to be broken I did some more googling. I am currently running .Net Framework version 4 and this still seems to be very much unresolved (!)

There is a bug issue posted to Microsoft and together with that a spended workaround, I would think it is a similar solution as described by Walt Stoneburner. You just use another created dependency property instead of the troublesome 'Command' property on copy-paste, the rest is treated by the helper class. You can download a zip from here, press the 'Show link' to access it. Thanks Bob Bao for posting it:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/637269/copying-a-command-bound-hyperlink-in-a-flowdocument-throws-an-exception

Microsoft seem to have released a solution by now, 'HyperlinkHelper' it is called. For some awkward reason they seem to have choosen to distribute it with in some team foundation dll(?) You can find documentation for it on the link below. If you are fortunate enough to be using Team Foundation server you might even be able to use the class directly. Otherwise, I would recommend reusing the solution provided above.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/microsoft.teamfoundation.controls.wpf.hyperlinkhelper

Comment: Thanks Henrik, you did a great job with locating some up to date information.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue, in a small POC althought I got it to work in a bigger project and I managed to find why. Don't know if it can helps, but here his the context and the solution.

The problem appeared when trying to bind a command to a Button in an Xceed datagrid, which itemSource was bind on a collection exposed in my viewModel.

THE VIEW :

```
<UserControl x:Class="UnIfied.Module.UI.Client.Screens.Alerts.AlertsView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:DataGrid="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid" xmlns:xcdg="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.Views;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid" xmlns:ThemePack="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.ThemePack;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.ThemePack.1">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid:DataGridControl  Grid.Column="0" 
                               Name="alertsBlotter" 
                               ItemsSource="{Binding AlertsSource}" 
                               SelectionMode="Single" 
                               NavigationBehavior="RowOnly" 
                               ItemScrollingBehavior="Immediate" ReadOnly="True"
                               AutoCreateColumns="false">
        <DataGrid:DataGridControl.Columns>
            <DataGrid:UnboundColumn FieldName="Acquit" Title="Acquit Alert" ReadOnly="True" ShowInColumnChooser="False">
                <DataGrid:UnboundColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button 
                            DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid:DataRow}}}"
                            Content="X" Command="{Binding AcquitAlertCommand}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid:UnboundColumn.CellContentTemplate>
            </DataGrid:UnboundColumn>
            <DataGrid:Column FieldName="AlertId" ReadOnly="True" Title="Alert Id" IsMainColumn="True" />
            <DataGrid:Column FieldName="Time" ReadOnly="True" Title="Creation Time" />
            <DataGrid:Column FieldName="AlertStatus" ReadOnly="True" Title="Status" />
            <DataGrid:Column FieldName="RelatedTrade"  ReadOnly="True" Title="CT Id" />
            <DataGrid:Column FieldName="Status" ReadOnly="True" Title="CT Status" />
        </DataGrid:DataGridControl.Columns>

        <DataGrid:DataGridControl.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGrid:ScrollTip}" TargetType="DataGrid:ScrollTip">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid:DataGridControl.Resources>
        <DataGrid:DataGridControl.View>
            <xcdg:TableView>
                <xcdg:TableView.Theme>
                    <ThemePack:WMP11Theme />
                </xcdg:TableView.Theme>
            </xcdg:TableView>
        </DataGrid:DataGridControl.View>
    </DataGrid:DataGridControl>
</Grid>
```

THE VIEWMODEL

```
class AlertsViewModel : Presenter<IAlerts>
{
    private readonly IAlertsService alertsService;
    public AlertsViewModel(IAlerts view, IAlertsService aService)
        : base(view)
    {
        alertsService = aService;
        view.SetDataContext(this);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<AlertAdapter> AlertsSource
    {
        get { return alertsService.AlertsSource; }
    }
}
```

THE ADAPTER (which will then be represented by a row in the datagrid). Relay command is a basic ICommand implementation.

```
public class AlertAdapter : BindableObject
{
    private readonly RelayCommand acquitAlert;

    public AlertAdapter()
    {
        AlertStatus = AlertStatus.Raised;
        acquitAlert = new RelayCommand(ExecuteAqcuiteAlert);
    }

    public RelayCommand AcquitAlertCommand
    {
        get { return acquitAlert; }
    }

    private void ExecuteAqcuiteAlert(object obj)
    {
        AlertStatus = AlertStatus.Cleared;
    }

    private static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs AlertStatusPropertyChanged = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AlertStatus");
    private AlertStatus alertStatus;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the AlertStatus
    /// </summary>
    public AlertStatus AlertStatus
    {
        get { return alertStatus; }
        set
        {
            if (AlertStatus != value)
            {
                alertStatus = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(AlertStatusPropertyChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    private static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs AlertIdPropertyChanged = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AlertId");
    private Guid alertId;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the AlertId
    /// </summary>
    public Guid AlertId
    {
        get { return alertId; }
        set
        {
            if (AlertId != value)
            {
                alertId = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(AlertIdPropertyChanged);
            }
        }
    }


    private static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs StatusPropertyChanged = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Status");
    private ComponentTradeStatus status;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the CtStatus
    /// </summary>
    public ComponentTradeStatus Status
    {
        get { return status; }
        set
        {
            if (Status != value)
            {
                status = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(StatusPropertyChanged);
            }
        }
    }


    private static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs RelatedTradePropertyChanged = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RelatedTrade");
    private Guid relatedTrade;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the RelatedTrade
    /// </summary>
    public Guid RelatedTrade
    {
        get { return relatedTrade; }
        set
        {
            if (RelatedTrade != value)
            {
                relatedTrade = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(RelatedTradePropertyChanged);
            }
        }
    }


    private static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs TimePropertyChanged = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Time");
    private DateTime time;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Time
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Time
    {
        get { return time; }
        set
        {
            if (Time != value)
            {
                time = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(TimePropertyChanged);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the exception generated as soon as my app tried to create an adapter and add it to the collection

System.NotSupportedException was unhandled
  Message="'CommandConverter' is unable to convert 'UnIfied.Module.UI.Client.Adapters.RelayCommand' to 'System.String'."
  Source="System"
  StackTrace:
       at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertToException(Object value, Type destinationType)
       at System.Windows.Input.CommandConverter.ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)
       at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertTo(Object value, Type destinationType)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.DefaultTemplate.DoDefaultExpansion(TextBlock textBlock, Object content, ContentPresenter container)
       (ETC.)

***The issue was caused by the fact that my datagrid was configured to AutoCreateColumns (i.e. based on the properties of the adapter). Just switched this property to false and then all went straight again.***

Hope this will help you guys !

--Bruno

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to solve this issue to make Command binding with dynamic resource so that parser do not resolve while trying to convert command to string.

```
<Hyperlink Command="{DynamicResource NavigationCommand}">Navigate</Hyperlink>
```

Check details of this solution here http://ciintelligence.blogspot.com/2011/11/wpf-copying-hyperlink-with-command.html